# How to create and use my own url(svc) for push notification in windows phone7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Hi iam new to windows phone push notification services.

My problem is

i should write a wcf service

By using this wcf service url i need to push the notification using one web application

and finally on windows phone i need to show all the notifications posted to that svc url.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented something like you want to achieve by reading and implementing this tutorial http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts/push_notifications, however in this example it only implements a service that sends push notifications, toasts and tile updates to be clear, to everyone that is subscribed, I modified it to send to the users I want...

I hope you find it useful :)
It also shows the implementation on Azure and on WP7...